# CMake Passed variables compiler is not able to compile a simple program

Tags: c++, c, linux, git, cmake

I am trying to cross compile an application using CMake. I have everything working when I hardcode the paths to the cross compiler. However, when I pass in the paths via command line arguments, it seems to not track them properly.

Here is my shell script, from which I clone a repo, apply a patch, and then attempt a cmake build:

```
   cmake -D BASE=$PATH_TO_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT -D BOOST_ROOT=$BOOST_ROOT -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake ../${GIT_PATH}/src/
```

Here is my toolchain.cmake file:

```
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1 )
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config")

message("Base: ${BASE}")
message("Boost: ${BOOST_ROOT}")

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${BASE}/sysroot")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${BASE}/sysroot/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${BASE}/sysroot/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-g++") 

set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${BASE}/sysroot")

set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)


include_directories(${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/local/include/)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib)

include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${BASE}/sysroot/usr/lib/)
set(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY libssl.so)
set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY libcrypto.so)
```

Again, if I hardcode ${BASE} in this toolchain file as /path/to/mipsel-linux-gcc, it works.

However, when I actually call this, I get this printout:

```
+ cmake -D BASE=/path/to/toolchain/root -D BOOST_ROOT=/home/matthew/boost/out -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake ../build/src/
Base: /path/to/toolchain/root
Boost: /home/matthew/boost/out
Base: /path/to/toolchain/root
Boost: /home/matthew/boost/out
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /path/to/toolchain/root/sysroot/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc
Base: 
Boost: 
-- Check for working C compiler: /path/to/toolchain/root/sysroot/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler
  "/path/to/toolchain/root/sysroot/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/matthew/Desktop/clones/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

Here you can see that it clearly *does* find the compilers, and identifies them both as GNU 4.7.3. However, notice the printouts *Base: /path/to/toolchain/root*. This message() directive was only listed one time in toolchain.cmake, and yet it prints out several times here, and eventually shows as a blank variable. After that, it complains that the C compiler doesn't work, even though it clearly then prints out the full path to that compiler.

I have seen similar problems of other people, but this seems different because it works fine when I hardcode the path in toolchain.cmake to the C and CXX compiler. I have tried with quotes around the C and CXX compiler directive, as well as without.

I am also interested in learning why my message directives print out so many times!

Thanks

Comment: `I am also interested in learning why my message directives print out so many times!` - It seems that third time it prints during compiler check. This check is actually a (separate) CMake project, which "inherits" your toolchain ... but not other definitions passed to `cmake`. Looks like parametrising toolchain with CMake variable is not a good idea: these variables are not passed to subprojects. BTW, CMake has a special variable for sysroot: [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html).

Answer (score 0):

The CMake is doing a test build to find out if the compiler is able to build a simple app (basically just containing `main()`). This might fail for multiple reasons, for example the compiler does not work with default CMake detected flags, etc.

You should check the `CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput.log` to see why the test compile failed.

To skip the compiler test, you might as well put the following to the toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
```

This will skip the compiler test, but of course the compilation might then fail later when you actually build your project.

Comment: First, I found the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS` and its CXX equivalent don't work. I had to use `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED=true`. Second, there is no point in skipping the compiler test, as the cmake introspection will probably trip up in a later step. There are ways to circumvent it but it is just putting a mask on top of a mask of a problem

Answer (score 0):

Check my reply here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207460115/comments/360002077699

Basically cmake during its system introspection will generate some files (test C/CXX files, Makefiles and even a new CMake project) through the try_compile command and then delete them by default.

If you want to be able to disable the deletion of these generated files and debug your issue you can add `--debug_trycompile` while running cmake and you will find some very useful information in root/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp